# systemProperties and integrationGlobalProperties conflict

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

So i have a situation when I need to use spring integration. So I create application context for it and then i describe my all logic in it. But now, I have an error something like this:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [java.util.Properties] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [integrationGlobalProperties, systemProperties]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1184)
    ... 61 more
```

Does someone faced with this problem with systemProperties and integrationGlobalProperties? What does it mean?

P.s. my application context is imported into another application context which has "default-autowire="byType"

Answer (score 0):

As you see your context has two bean of `java.util.Properties`. That means that you can't inject `byType`.

Use `@Qualifier("systemProperties")` to restrict it to specific `Properties`.

The `integrationGlobalProperties` isn't only one bean which is populated by Framework. And it isn't a surprise that autowire `byType` is more and more bad for real applications.

Comment: where to put it? I cannot find where to put annotation on systemProperties :/ Because these properties is from spring..

Comment: Show, please, how you autowire it.

Comment: I do not, because it is from spring itself. It is not a custom systemproperties class.I just put default-autowire="byName" for some classes I needed but do not specify systemProperties anywhere. And now i have conflict for with integration properties and systemproperties which are constants if i understand it well.

Comment: You have some bean which is autowired with `Properties`. You have to specify `byName` for this one. Which bean is affected you can see by that StackTrace.

Comment: Yes, it looks simple from the first glance, but there is no bean by name "systemProperties" :)

Comment: Then `systemProperties` is a built-in bean from some Framework, as `integrationGlobalProperties` is from Spring Integration. One of your bean has `setProperties` and if it is autowired `byType` you end up with that ambiguity issue.

Comment: Yes, it is by default wiring byType, and I cannot change it. ..... there is a method inside called "getBeanbyType". I can't change it at all. I hope theres

Comment: Well, it's bad design, though. As you see there is no guaranty that your `Properties` bean will be only one by this type. That `getBeanbyType` method has to be protected from this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced same issue. After some research I have decided to wirte a `CustomBeanPostProcessor` class (implementing `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`) which will try to find conflicting bean and change its *'autowire'* property to *'byName'*, thus avoiding conflict.

Please have a look at a code below:

```
public class CustomBeanPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor{
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        if (beanFactory.containsBean("integrationGlobalProperties")){
           //Choose on of the options - either disable autowiring for bean completly,
           //or change autowiring type
           beanFactory.getBeanDefinition("integrationGlobalProperties").setAutowireCandidate(false);
           beanFactory.getBeanDefinition("integrationGlobalProperties").setAttribute("autowire", "byName");
        } 
    }
}
```

Do not forget to declare this class as Spring bean as well:

```
<bean class="edu.stackoverflow.spring.misc.CustomBeanPostProcessor"/>
```